# Ember App Kit 'Unable to find view at path'

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit, ember.js-view

I have a template **templates/articles.hbs** with the code:

`{{view "carousel"}}`

The above statement must be correct, as it is stated in the Getting Started: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/wiki/Getting-Started#resolving-from-template-helpers

At **views/carousel.js** the simple code:

```
var CarouselView = Ember.View.extend({    
    classNames: ['carousel']
});
export default CarouselView;
```

This causes however the following error:

```
Assertion failed: Unable to find view at path 'carousel' ember.js:3231
Assertion failed: You must pass a view to the #view helper, not carousel ()
```

I have tried to add carousel.js to views/articles/carousel.js. I have tried different `{{view}}` names such ass App.CarouselView etc, but that all does not work.

What are I am missing here guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the guides it says you have to pass a view class to the view helper, so does the error message. The wiki might be outdated.

Also I think you've mistakenly defined `var CarouselView =` instead of `App.CarouselView = ...`

Comment: Hi, did you see I use Ember App Kit? The code you mention is the syntax used by ES6 module transpiler.

Comment: Sorry no I didn't notice ;) Try restarting the grunt server. That did it for me. The syntax was indeed correct

Comment: Wow, what a laughing moment is this... Restarted grunt, and hey it works! You need to know that I was trying for hours to get this working. You Saved My Day! :)

Comment: Quick note, if your view has two words, like `NavBarView` you use it with it hyphenated in your template, like `{{view "nav-bar"}}`